# One polygon layer for an area with different projects in the same layer?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I was wondering if it is possible (maybe not ?) to make a structure so that I can have diffrient information (projekts) over the same area/point in the same layer. This would be for an overview of the projects geographically over all areas and to see information about the projects. I don't know if there is any other way to make this.

Let's say there is a harbour with 3 basins in the same area. The area is called ex. Stark harbour and incloud this 3 basins. I could mark out this area with a polygon or a point. Now let's say that this basins has maintenance like repration every half year and that is a new projektnumber everytime. Now there are 3 basins in this area and I would like to keep this polygons/points as one layer named by the area, Stark harbour. 
I could of course creat a new layer for every basin and keep track of the information separately, but this would create so many layers when there are many harbours with a lot of basins around the country.

If there is any other way to make something like this could you show me or give me a link?

I will just post an example of what I would like Qgis to have and maybe clear up my bad explanation.

First a polygone over the area and then you would click with identify to get a pop up
[image]
In the attribute field you would be able to click on the project number to get to a new attribute with information regarding that project

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I was going to do this, I woild maybe store a url for each harbour or basin postgis and use that to open a webpage in which to read or update the maintenance information. If you do not have the possibility to set up a webserver, What you showed would not be too hard to write in a plugin, or have a look here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343364/selecting-features-using-attributes-of-another-file-in-qgis to see some ideas of how to select attrobutes in one table defined on selection in another table.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am not at that lvl yet to write my own plugin 
unfortunately :/. For now there is no possibility to set up a webserver.